# How to disable the link if the checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How can I disable the **link(delete and view)**  if the checkbox is unchecked.

This is my code

```
<table><form>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th style="width:100px;"><center>Last Name</center></th>
            <th style="width:100px;"><center>First Name</center></th>
            <th style="width:auto;"><center>Email</center></th>
            <th style="width:100px;"><center>Birthday</center></th>
            <th style="width:auto;"><center>Action</center></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"box\">";
            echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['bdate']."</td>";
            echo "";
            echo "<td><center>";
            echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=".$row['id']."\" style=\"text-decoration:none\" class=\"btn\" id=\"delete\">DELETE</a> ";
            echo "<a href=\"personal_information.php?id=".$row['id']."\" style=\"text-decoration:none\" class=\"btn\" id=\"view\">VIEW</a> ";
            echo "</td></center></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
        ?>
    </form></table>
```

Here is my **jQuery script**(example if I want to disable VIEW link only)

```
<script>
        jQuery('#box').click(function () {
    //check if checkbox is checked
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {

        jQuery('#view').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable input

    } else {
        jQuery('#view').attr('disabled', true); //disable input
    }
});
    </script>
```

I want to disable the each view and delete per row if the checkbox is uncheck how can I do it? or my jQuery is wrong? Can you give me an example for checkall box

Comment: check all box query is here http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kXYuU/ and  #view is id or not

Comment: Your html is not valid, form-element is not allowed as a immadiate child of table-element

Comment: @UdhayTitus it is an ID to disable the VIEW link if the checkbox is uncheck

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check"/><label for="check">checkbox</label>
```

Google

[Check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/hQJXW/3/)

Comment: so i should put <label for="box"> per row?

Comment: No no its not mandatory you can use as your wish now a days so many technologies are there like bootstrap class and blah blah blah..just try in google hope you will find.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors can't not be disabled only form-related elements can be disabled (`input`, `button`, `textarea`, etc.) What you should do is either remove the `href` attribute or hide the anchor element...

```js
$(function() {
  $("#chkRemove").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("a").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
    } else {
      $("a").each(function(idx, element) {
        $(element).attr("href", $(element).data("link"));
      });
    }
  });
  
  $("#chkHide").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("a").hide();
    } else {
      $("a").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.links {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.links a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <input id="chkRemove" type="checkbox" />Remove href attribute
</div>
<div>
  <input id="chkHide" type="checkbox" />Hide anchors
</div>

<div class="links">
  <a href="http://google.com" data-link="http://google.com">Google Link</a>

  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" data-link="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow Link</a>
</div>
```

Also, as a side note. Never use the `attr` function to handle the state of the checkbox or a radio button. Always use the [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function instead

```
$(selector).prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: in just one row its ok but the rest it doesnt do anything

Comment: @reyjoel not sure what you mean, I don't what selectors you're using

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about php but try this:

```
....
.
.
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"box\" onchange="myfunction()">";
echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['bdate']."</td>";
echo "";
echo "<td><center>";
echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=".$row['id']."\" style=\"text-decoration:none\" class=\"btn\" id=\"delete\"><input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete"></a> ";
echo "<a href=\"personal_information.php?id=".$row['id']."\" style=\"text-decoration:none\" class=\"btn\" id=\"view\"><input type="button" id="view" value="View"></a> ";
.
.
.
...
```

And the JavaScript goes like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('delete').disabled = !this.checked;
    document.getElementById('view').disabled = !this.checked;
}
</script>
```

Comment: how can i make it into jQuery sir?

Comment: does it effect per row?

Comment: Per row? Do you mean affecting all rows? From your code, I see all the rows are going to have the same ID so if you select even one checkbox, it should enable delete and view buttons.